# Apple Mach O Linker Error popped up out of nowhere

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

My current project is driving me absolutely crazy

The issue is with sdk's that I have added to my project. Such as google ads, parse, Facebook and adcolony.

I added them when I first started my project weeks ago and they worked fine.

Today I opened my project, cleaned it, and I started getting "Lexical or preprocessor issues" for all of the added sdk's.

I removed them all and added them again and the "lexical or preprocessor issues" were gone but were replaced 33 "Apple Mach O Linker Errors"

I have no idea what I have done wrong as nothing has changed. I am using the latest version of all of the sdk's.

As I said the project had been building fine for weeks.

Please help me as this is driving me absolutely crazy!

Also I know that there are quite a few questions on Stack Overflow already with answers that address the mach-O linker Errors but none of them are helping me.

Here is a sample of the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__throw_bad_alloc()", referenced from:
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef* std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_allocate_and_copy<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*>(unsigned long, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for google_breakpadPFC_::IosExceptionMinidumpGeneratorPFC_ in ParseCrashReporting(ios_exception_minidump_generator.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
```

Comment: What do the linker errors say?

Comment: @NobodyNada thanks for formatting. I'm quite new. Should I add more of there errors? This is about 1/10 of the error

Comment: Only if the errors are much different than the ones you posted.

Comment: What are names of all the source code files in your project?

Comment: @NobodyNada Sorry I'm not the most experienced dev. By source code, do you mean the header and implementation files that I have created?

Comment: Yes.  Source code is human-readable computer code.  I need the names of the files containing source code.

Comment: AppDelegate, ViewController, StartViewController, MainMenuViewController, PowerUpsViewController

Comment: What are the extensions of those filenames?

Comment: AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, ViewController.h, ViewController.m, StartViewController.h, StartViewController.m, MainMenuViewController.h, MainMenuViewController.m, PowerUpsViewController.h, PowerUpsViewController.m

Comment: Which files use google ads?

Comment: I have just imported the framework for future use

Comment: Okay.  I think I see the problem.  In which file(s) do you import it?

Comment: I haven't imported google ads into any header or implementation file yet. I have only imported it into the project.

Comment: Oh, then I'm not sure of the problem.  Is google ads the only framework causing problems? (Do you still have the errors if you remove Google ads?)

Comment: Ye I'm getting errors from parse, adcolony and Facebook also. It's making me so angry. I've used them in other projects before with no problems. I'm supposed to be spending my Sunday working on my new game but instead I'm spending hours working out these annoying errors. I think I'll just scrap it and start again.

Comment: Maybe some bad intermediate  files are being reused.  Try pressing Shift-Command-Option-K and then rebuilding your project.

Comment: Na still getting the errors

Comment: Hmm.  I have one more idea.  How did you add the frameworks?

Comment: Originally, I dragged them into the project. When I deleted them and added them again I went to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > Add Other

Comment: This is pretty similar to a problem I once had.  In Finder, go to your project folder.  Look around in it and it's sub-folders.  Can you find a folder that ends in `.framework`?

Comment: Theres a few, adcolony.framework, parse.framework and others

Comment: Delete them.  I've had this exact problem before.

Comment: I'm getting the Lexical or Preprocessor errors again now. I'll try adding the frameworks again

Comment: Okay, but make sure "Copy items into destination's group folder (if needed)" is unchecked.

Comment: What errors do you have now?  Preprocessor or linker?  Also, what did the prepeocessor errors say?

Comment: Okay. It's building now. I deleted all of the frameworks and added them again. I am getting Apple Mach O Linker Warnings. Only warnings though so it still builds and runs properly. Thank you so much for your time. You are very generous

Comment: You're welcome.  I had this exact same problem a few years ago (except with Core Animation instead of the frameworks you're using).  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few years ago.  It is caused by leaving "Copy items into destination's group folder (if needed)" checked when adding a framework.  This option tells Xcode to copy the files you are adding into your project directory.  This is good for resources such as images, sounds, and so on since it keeps your whole project in one place instead of scattered all over the computer, but if you do this with a framework you will confuse the prepeocessor and/or linkers because it messes up search paths.